# Accessing full size (851x315) timeline cover photo via graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I notice that when I access the timeline cover photo URL via the Graph API (using PHP) the photo returned is 720x266 instead of 851x315.  Either using, `<graph api url>/userId/?field=cover` or by accessing the url in `['cover']['source']` of the json array returned when accessing `<graph api url>/userID`

I've been unable to find a way to retrieve the full size cover photo.  Using firebug I can see Facebook load the full size 851x315 image, the only difference in the URL seems to be that the one returned by the API has 720x720 in the path,

### What Facebook loads:

> http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg

### What the Graph API returns

> http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg

Is there a way way I can access that full size cover photo URL directly?  I could parse the URL returned by the API to strip the 720x720 but I am hoping the is a more elegant way of obtaining the full size cover photo URL directly.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I did this for now,

$large_cover_photo = explode('s720x720/', $main_page['cover']['source']);
$large_cover_photo = implode('', $large_cover_photo);

$main_page is the json array returned when I queried /userid

But finding a way to access the full size image directly would still be best, if anyone knows how.

Comment: The way u did it is ok. Now go find a real challenge ;)

Answer (score 6):

## Accessing full-size timeline cover photo of facebook user

---

In php , we can do the following.
Its a small hack,and i dont gurantee that it will work for lifetime.

As you can see, there is a `s720x720` in the returned photo url. Now we are going to replace that with  `l720` (L720). with the help of preg_replace() in php .

---

```
$coverphoto_url="https://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg";

$coverphoto_url = preg_replace('/s720/i','l720',$coverphoto_url);
```

---

This will return,

> https: //a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/**l720x720**/xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg

---

You can also do this with javascript.

```
coverphoto_url = coverphoto_url.replace(/s720/i, 'l720');
```

---

If you dont know how to retrieve coverphoto via graph API,then please read this question.

[How to get a securl cover URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702442/how-to-get-a-securl-cover-url/14355991#14355991)

hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Just pointing out to future readers that this works, but its not 100% reliable.

If you plan to use this, at least attach an `onerror` handler to the `<img>` to revert back if it fails

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is now broken with the new Facebook Graph API, I was able to get the high quality cover photo in JavaScript with this function:

```
FB.api("/hawaiianchimp?fields=cover", function(response){
        FB.api("/"+response.cover.id, function(response){
            var img_src = response.images[0].source;
        });
      });
```

This gets the cover photo ID and then does a second Graph API call to get the image source

Answer (score 1):

It appears in my testing that this part of the url is the crux of the matter:
`.../c0.0.851.315/...`

So therefore perform a request like this:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$id}?fields=cover";

// // this points it to the actual banner, not the fullsized one 
$key_851 = 'c0.0.851.315';

$response = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );

if( is_object( $response ) && property_exists( $response->cover , 'source' ) ) {
    $coverphoto_url = preg_replace( '/s720(\w*\.*)\d*(?<!\/)/i', $key_851 ,$response->cover->source );
    echo $coverphoto_url;
}
```