# How to get a securl cover URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl, https, cover

I'm tryng to get the cover url of a FBpage using:

```
$fql_query_url = "https://graph.facebook.com"
    ."/$fb_id[id]?fields=cover"
."";
try {
    $fql_query_result = @file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
    $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
} catch(Exception $o){   }
$cover = $fql_query_obj[cover][source];
```

I get an http://... url and not the https://... url

any tips?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#pictures

Comment: Why not you replace http:// to https://

Comment: Because looks like the FB secure url is different.

Comment: If a try to get the cover source in the develore tools I get a different subdomain secure url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe pointed out, you need to specify you need a secure URL by setting the return_ssl_resources argument to 1: https://graph.facebook.com/wtf.no.username/picture?return_ssl_resources=1.

Edit: Please note that this isn't FQL (Facebook Query Language), this is just a standard API call.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the url, you can replace http to https with `preg_replace()` in PHP.

```
$cover = $fql_query_obj[cover][source];
$secure_cover = preg_replace('/^http(?=:\/\/)/i','https',$cover);
```

As far as i tested, it works fine.

You can also change this with javascript.

```
cover = cover.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
```

hope this help someone :)