# Accessing full size (851x315) timeline cover photo via graph api with offset crop

Tags: facebook, api, photo, cover

This is a continuous question of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074207/3269910

the solution seems fine c0.0.851.315

but the c0.0 values are pointing to 0x0 position of the images

what i want is the image with offset_y . if an offset_y: 20,

ie, i want the same size and part of image, what i am seeing in my page timeline in a api call.

Is it possible to do this ?

Note: if i change c0.0  the zero value to some other then it is pointing to pixels but offset_y is % i think.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had discussion with  Facebook Platform Team;

They are not ready to share the manual calculation to us.

and yes, it is possible to calculate value of c0.XXXX manually using your API offset_y value.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$fb_page_cover_json  =  json_decode( file_get_contents( 'https://graph.facebook.com/11111111?fields=cover'));

$fb_cover_image_url = $fb_page_cover_json->cover->source;

$image_info = getimagesize($fb_cover_image_url);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];                 

echo getTop($fb_page_cover_json->cover->offset_y,$image_width,$image_height);


function getTop($offset_y,$image_width,$image_height) {
    $cover_w = 851;
    $cover_h = 315;
    $img_w = $image_width;
    $img_h = $image_height;
    $real_img_h = ($cover_w * $img_h / $img_w) - $cover_h;
    $result = ($real_img_h * $offset_y / 100 * -1);

    return floor($result);
}
```

The method getTop will return the c0.XXX value.

Hope this helps some one.